# Add list to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have an initial array that looks like that:

```
[[2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [3, 0]]
```

after I use np.asarray(arr, dtype = object) it becomes like that:

```
[list([2, 3, 0]) list([4, 5, 0]) list([4, 0]) list([5, 0]) list([3, 0])]
```

and the problem is that I cant add another list because after adding one with `np.append(arr, list([0])` its look like that:

```
[list([2, 3, 0]) list([4, 5, 0]) list([4, 0]) list([5, 0]) list([3, 0]) 0]
```

instead of

```
[list([2, 3, 0]) list([4, 5, 0]) list([4, 0]) list([5, 0]) list([3, 0]) list([0])]
```

and if I add more, for example with `np.append(arr, list([1,2,3,0])` they are just added to the end as a simple number.

So the question is how I could add a list to the NumPy array that I could use with arr[i] to print the entire list?

Comment: Stick with lists.  Object dtype arrays aren't worth the bother if this is your goal.

Comment: I highly suggest you don't do this to begin with. There is *no* advantage to using `numpy.ndarray` here. Just use a regular `list`

Answer (score 0):

`np.append` automatically flattens the list you pass it, unless you're append one array to another rectangular array. From [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) (emphasis mine):

> `axis` : `int`, optional
> The axis along which `values` are appended.  **If `axis` is not given, both `arr` and `values` are flattened before use.**

In your case, I'd convert the array to a list, add the item, then convert it back to an array:

```
>>> a
array([list([2, 3, 0]), list([4, 5, 0]), list([4, 0]), list([5, 0]), list([3, 0])], dtype=object)

>>> np.array(a.tolist() + [[0,1,2,3]])
array([list([2, 3, 0]), list([4, 5, 0]), list([4, 0]), list([5, 0]), list([3, 0]), list([0, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

With lists it's easy to add a list:

```
In [41]: alist =[[2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [3, 0]]
In [42]: alist.append([0])
In [43]: alist
Out[43]: [[2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [3, 0], [0]]

In [53]: arr = np.array(alist,object)
In [54]: arr
Out[54]: 
array([list([2, 3, 0]), list([4, 5, 0]), list([4, 0]), list([5, 0]),
       list([3, 0]), list([0])], dtype=object)
```

To do something similar with arrays, we have to first construct an object dtype array containing the desired list:

```
In [55]: toadd = np.array([None]); toadd[0] = [0]
In [56]: toadd
Out[56]: array([list([0])], dtype=object)
In [57]: np.concatenate((arr, toadd))
Out[57]: 
array([list([2, 3, 0]), list([4, 5, 0]), list([4, 0]), list([5, 0]),
       list([3, 0]), list([0]), list([0])], dtype=object)
```

The concatenate combines a (5,) array with a (1,).  The number of dimensions have to match.